# Is it possible to cancel a WPF Binding to a Control.Template property using Binding.DoNothing?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, binding

I want to easily use a read only template for a control when the value of a property in my model is  true. To do that I've created a IValueConverter which returns it's parameter (a template in this case) when the source value is true, and Binding.DoNothing when false.

When I apply this to my control, I get a control without Template.

Comment: I've tried simply returning Binding.DoNothing in my converter, so I know the problem is not there.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could use a DataTemplateSelector rather than IValueConverter, something along the lines of:

```
//namespace MyProject.ViewUtilities
public class MyDataTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var localFrameworkElement = container as FrameworkElement;
        var modelObject = item as ModelObject;

        if(modelObject.BoolProperty){
            return Template(localFrameworkElement, "WhenTrueDataTemplate");
        }
        else
        {
            return Template(localFrameworkElement, "WhenFalseDataTemplate");
        }
    }


    private DataTemplate Template(FrameworkElement localFrameworkElement, string resourceKeyString)
    {
        return localFrameworkElement.FindResource(resourceKeyString) as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

Used something like:

```
<ComboBox xmlns:mpvu="MyProject.ViewUtilities"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyModelObjectCollection}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <mpvu:MyDataTemplateSelector/>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ComboBox>
```

If this isn't what you want, perhaps add some sample code to your post.

Comment: I've actually solved it using something similar to your method (I've used a Behavior), but I was rather curious as to why the DoNothing didn't work...